# babel crash figures

Tags: babel, texlive-2020

after upgraing latex to
marcos@averell ~/tmp $ dpkg -l | grep texlive-base
ii  texlive-base                               2019.20200218-1

I have a problem with figures. In old latex (2017.20180305-1) it worked.
Here an example of the latex file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage[brazil]{babel}

\begin {document}
\chapter {Teste}


\section{Teste}

 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam a est dapibus, finibus massa vitae, imperdiet mi. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam semper nisl et ipsum efficitur dignissim. Duis at tortor a risus mattis interdum. Phasellus bibendum diam vitae urna ornare, id gravida lorem pretium. Integer a mi et dolor posuere pellentesque. Aenean porttitor facilisis sem vitae posuere. Curabitur auctor nulla mauris, at rutrum risus convallis at~\ref{test_label}.

Duis et finibus lectus. Fusce a facilisis diam, et ullamcorper massa. Proin euismod eu velit a congue. Praesent quis fringilla nunc, in ornare mi. Maecenas sed egestas velit. Nunc ullamcorper ex sit amet convallis facilisis. Vestibulum blandit nunc metus, eu iaculis lacus varius ac. Phasellus ut dolor lacus. Cras sed nisl lorem.

Sed mattis ullamcorper accumsan. Sed tincidunt accumsan erat et eleifend. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Morbi fringilla, dui vitae molestie eleifend, tellus tortor malesuada augue, non blandit odio leo placerat urna. Pellentesque vulputate erat eget ligula imperdiet, at laoreet dolor feugiat. Quisque a ante vel dolor aliquam mattis et nec nulla. Nulla rutrum rhoncus nisl, in rhoncus est consectetur ut. Etiam tortor sem, tincidunt at diam nec, pharetra accumsan magna.


\begin{center}
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \begin{verbatim}
    begin
        linha 1;
        linha 2;
        linha 3;
        linha 4;
        linha 5;
        linha 6;
        linha 7;
        linha 8;
    end.
    \end{verbatim}
    \caption{leo placerat rhoncus est consectetur}
\label{test_label}
\end{figure}
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

After compiling the figure is not there and the reference to the figure doesn't work.
The figure is replaced by double quotes """""" and the reference apears unknown (??)
If I comment out the \usepackage[brazil]{babel} the problem desapear and all work fine.
Thanks for any help.

PS. I'm using pdflatex veersion 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20

Comment: Compiles fine for me, but 2019 sounds a bit older than my system. Unrelated: don't put a center environment around a figure, \centering belongs into the figure.

Comment: Unrelated that center env does nothing, it ought to go inside the figure env